# Does anyone have any topic tests for conics (from maths extension 2)?

Tags: conic-sections

Does anyone have any topic tests, trial tests or half yearly test questions for conics (maths extension 2 conic sections)? I know the syllabus has changed, but I am trying to re-learn all of the maths extension 2 content I learnt many years ago in high school for multiple reasons. A topic test on conics would be perfect; or a compilation of trial exam or half yearly exam (from SPECIFIC schools) questions on specifically conics would be great. Please no HSC questions (I already have all the HSC exams). I am looking for exams set by specific schools on conics. I would really prefer really challenging or difficult questions on conics, but any conics questions will do. Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you can Select the tag "conics" on this site... and give priority to those questions or answers with many upvotes which, generally speaking, means they involve interesting things...